# Pureweb and VUE application

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, unreal-engine4

I have sample VueJS(frontend) application and Unreal Project.

I have uploaded the Unreal Project to https://console.pureweb.io/, after that I can't find the documentation about connectivity the Pureweb to VueJS application for share Unreal Project in client side.
I would be happy for any information about connect Pureweb and JS-application

The only useful documentation so far:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pureweb/platform-streaming-agent